# Tachyon mode in Brane-Antibrane system (Type II)

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, branes, tachyon, string-field-theory

Lets First start with coincident $D3$ brane- $D3$ Brane system. Superstring stretch between these two contain a Tachyon mode But GSO projection removes this. For open string, $D$ branes serve just as a boundary condition.

Now consider coincident $D3$ brane- anti $ D3$ Brane system. Again it will contain Tachyon mode. Why don't we say that GSO projection will remove this mode? We need a Tachyon condensation mechanism. I am guessing we can't apply GSO projection over here. Is there any explanation from Green- Schwarz superstring quantization?

I know from the closed string point of view that this system is unstable. Gravitational force adds up to the force due to RR charges.

I am reading this paper https://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/9805170.